# Change keyboard language on runtime

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, multilingual

I am writing an application for health which have multiple languages like English, Russian and Arabic etc. Displaying the the different languages is not an issue but when i start typing in input box it types the default english language, I want to do it this way if my session is set for Arabic then the keyboard should auto write Arabic instead of english and same for rest of the languages.

The application is supposed to be developed in php + mysql.

Comment: u have to use some js text editor that support unicode format and supoport multiple language

Comment: Do you mean switching the input language of your os by using javascript? Doubt that it can be done..

Comment: I would not bother. It is up to the user. I change input language and spell checking all the time. Default is Dutch for me

Comment: Only possible in a very nasty way. Catch all keystrokes with JS and map them to specific characters for a given language. But please don't do this as it will drive people crazy, and likely break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know language settings are much of the OS issue rather than to be handled in the web application, if the user wants to type in some other language say Dutch, he/she can change the keyboard language and type in it.

The language can be changed by

> Run > intl.cpl > keyboard and languages > change keyboard

Comment: Okay i got the point, so it is not m y concern to handle input fields language.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so this issue can be handled through any programming language. Language settings is related to your OS. If your OS hasn't that language pack which your application supports then?